# how to know the remote access is over

Tags: c#, windows-7, remote-desktop

I use the property [SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.terminalserversession.aspx) can know the destop is access by remote or not.
But when the remote access is over,the user maybe close the remote connect.
Can i get the datetime when the user close the remote connect.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spin up a thread to monitor that value at an interval (or use a timer).  When it returns false you know it ended within the last interval.

Answer (score 0):

Yep -- using the [Cassia library](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/), that would be `new TerminalServicesManager().CurrentSession.DisconnectTime`.